# RichTextBox programmatic formatting backspace behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I have encountered another problem with `RichTextBox`. When you have a text range colored like this:

```
var range = new TextRange(TextInput.Document.ContentStart,
TextInput.Document.ContentEnd);
range.Text = "asdfghjk";

var colored = new TextRange(TextInput.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(3, LogicalDirection.Forward),
TextInput.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(7, LogicalDirection.Forward));
colored.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Blue);
```

And in your change listener you have something like this:

```
var range = new TextRange(TextInput.Document.ContentStart, TextInput.Document.ContentEnd);
if (range.Text.Length == 9)
     range.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Black);
```

When one of the characters colored blue is deleted using backspace (delete key works fine, I think), and you start typing immediately **the text that appears is blue**, as it was before formatting. I'm interested in why is that happening and what are ways of avoiding it.

Comment: I don't fully understand your problem as I can't reproduce the behavior you describe. If I delete a blue character (reducing the visible string length to 7), the whole string turns black. 

It appears that Text.Length is reporting 2 characters longer than the visible length of your string so your Length check in your change handler is being hit as soon as you delete a character.

Comment: The two other chars are "\r\n", and I have said:
When one of the characters colored blue is deleted ... **and you start typing immediately** the text remains blue, and I have meant, the text that will appear under cursor, I will fix that.

Comment: Ah I wasn't aware that a Document automatically added a carriage return and line break to the end of its Content. It doesn't reflect that in the RichTextBox as the caret is at the end of your string (immediately following the 'k').

Comment: I don't quite understand if you are still unable to reproduce it. Please ask if you need any other explanation, but I solved my problem by detecting backspace press in `KeyDownPreview` and deleting chars 'manually'.